# Are properties strong if you omit the keyword strong for ARC conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have just converted my project to ARC using the automatic conversation tool but none of the properties were converted to strong, just left (nonatomic)?

I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1) and it says all the properties should be (strong, nonatomic)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ARC enabled, properties default to `strong`:

> A property of retainable object pointer type which is synthesized without a source of ownership has the ownership of its associated instance variable, if it already exists; otherwise, [beginning Apple 3.1, LLVM 3.1] its ownership is implicitly strong. Prior to this revision, it was ill-formed to synthesize such a property.

From [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property)

Comment: Nube here - so the the code strong doesn't even need to appear anymore?

Comment: @TheLearner it doesn't, but it is still a good practice, as it clarifies what you are doing.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes you need to use strong else the compiler gives an issue.  The scenario was when I alloc'ed a instance  e.g. self.property = ... alloc.  I was forced to use strong.